# JS Add Input to Form Refreshes Page And Does Not Input

Tags: javascript, html

I did some research on this topic and I found nothing. My apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have a form that asks the user for four places they visited in the past 14 days. However, since obviously they can visit more than 4 places, I wanted to create a script to add a new input set. Here is my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-PHcOkPmOshsMBC+vtJdVr5Mwb7r0LkSVJPlPrp/IMpU=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var numPlaces = 4;

            function addPlace() {
                numPlaces++;
                console.log(numPlaces);
                var place = document.createElement("DIV");
                place.id = "p" + numPlaces;

                var group1 = document.createElement("DIV");
                group1.className = "form-group";

                var label1 = document.createElement("LABEL");
                label1.className = "custom-control-label";
                label1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                label1.innerHTML = "Place " + numPlaces;

                var address = document.createElement("INPUT");
                address.type = "text";
                address.className = "form-control";
                address.id = "place" + numPlaces;
                address.placeholder = "Enter Address of Place you Visited";

                group1.appendChild(label1);
                group1.appendChild(address);

                var group2 = document.createElement("DIV");
                group2.className = "form-group";

                var label2 = document.createElement("LABEL");
                label2.className = "custom-control-label";
                label2.innerHTML = "Enter the day you visited this place.";

                var date = document.createElement("INPUT");
                date.type = "date";
                date.className = "form-control";
                date.id = "date" + numPlaces;

                group2.appendChild(label2);
                group2.appendChild(date);

                var group3 = document.createElement("DIV");
                group3.className = "form-group";

                var label3 = document.createElement("LABEL");
                label3.className = "custom-control-label";
                label3.innerHTML = "Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?";

                var amDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
                amDiv.className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline";

                var amInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
                amInput.type = "radio";
                amInput.className = "custom-control-input";
                amInput.id = "am" + numPlaces;
                amInput.name = "time" + numPlaces;

                var label4 = document.createElement("LABEL");
                label4.className = "custom-control-label";
                label4.for = amInput.id;
                label4.innerHTML = "Morning";

                amDiv.appendChild(amInput);
                amDiv.appendChild(label4);

                var pmDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
                pmDiv.className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline";

                var pmInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
                pmInput.type = "radio";
                pmInput.className = "custom-control-input";
                pmInput.id = "pm" + numPlaces;
                pmInput.name = "time" + numPlaces;

                var label5 = document.createElement("LABEL");
                label5.className = "custom-control-label";
                label5.for = pmInput.id;
                label5.innerHTML = "Afternoon";

                pmDiv.appendChild(pmInput);
                pmDiv.appendChild(label5);

                group3.appendChild(amDiv);
                group3.appendChild(pmDiv);

                place.appendChild(group1);
                place.appendChild(group2);
                place.appendChild(group3);

                document.getElementById("addedPlaces").appendChild(place);
            }
        </script>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Am I At Risk?</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="userForm.php">Enter Details<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="governmentForm.php">Form for Government</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Please enter the various places you visited in the past 14 days.</label>
                </div>
                <div id="p1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 1</b></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place1" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date1"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am1" name="time1" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="am1">Morning</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm1" name="time1" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm1">Afternoon</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="p2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 2</b></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place2" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date2"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am2" name="time2" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="am2">Morning</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm2" name="time2" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm2">Afternoon</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="p3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 3</b></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place3" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date3"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am3" name="time3" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="am3">Morning</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm3" name="time3" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm3">Afternoon</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="p4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 4</b></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place4" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date4"></input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am4" name="time4" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="am4">Morning</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm4" name="time4" checked>
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm4">Afternoon</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div id="addedPlaces"></div>

                <button onclick="addPlace();">Add Place</button>


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My logic was to literally duplicate the input I already set for each place, but to duplicate it for an additional place. However, when I do this, it seems to refresh the page and it doesn't even add the elements. It should add it to the div "addedPlaces". Actually, it seems to partially add it and then immediately refresh the page.

I could not find something regarding this refreshing issue. Is there some other method instead of `appendChild()` that won't refresh the page, or is there a way to set it to not refresh the page? Or is there something that triggered the refresh that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of button is `submit` so just adding `type='button'` on Add Place Button Resolves your issue

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- BootStrap 4 CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <!-- BootStrap 4 JS -->
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var numPlaces = 4;

function addPlace() {
  numPlaces++;
  console.log(numPlaces);
  var place = document.createElement("DIV");
  place.id = "p" + numPlaces;

  var group1 = document.createElement("DIV");
  group1.className = "form-group";

  var label1 = document.createElement("LABEL");
  label1.className = "custom-control-label";
  label1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  label1.innerHTML = "Place " + numPlaces;

  var address = document.createElement("INPUT");
  address.type = "text";
  address.className = "form-control";
  address.id = "place" + numPlaces;
  address.placeholder = "Enter Address of Place you Visited";

  group1.appendChild(label1);
  group1.appendChild(address);

  var group2 = document.createElement("DIV");
  group2.className = "form-group";

  var label2 = document.createElement("LABEL");
  label2.className = "custom-control-label";
  label2.innerHTML = "Enter the day you visited this place.";

  var date = document.createElement("INPUT");
  date.type = "date";
  date.className = "form-control";
  date.id = "date" + numPlaces;

  group2.appendChild(label2);
  group2.appendChild(date);

  var group3 = document.createElement("DIV");
  group3.className = "form-group";

  var label3 = document.createElement("LABEL");
  label3.className = "custom-control-label";
  label3.innerHTML =
    "Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?";

  var amDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  amDiv.className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline";

  var amInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  amInput.type = "radio";
  amInput.className = "custom-control-input";
  amInput.id = "am" + numPlaces;
  amInput.name = "time" + numPlaces;

  var label4 = document.createElement("LABEL");
  label4.className = "custom-control-label";
  label4.for = amInput.id;
  label4.innerHTML = "Morning";

  amDiv.appendChild(amInput);
  amDiv.appendChild(label4);

  var pmDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  pmDiv.className = "custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline";

  var pmInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  pmInput.type = "radio";
  pmInput.className = "custom-control-input";
  pmInput.id = "pm" + numPlaces;
  pmInput.name = "time" + numPlaces;

  var label5 = document.createElement("LABEL");
  label5.className = "custom-control-label";
  label5.for = pmInput.id;
  label5.innerHTML = "Afternoon";

  pmDiv.appendChild(pmInput);
  pmDiv.appendChild(label5);

  group3.appendChild(amDiv);
  group3.appendChild(pmDiv);

  place.appendChild(group1);
  place.appendChild(group2);
  place.appendChild(group3);

  document.getElementById("addedPlaces").appendChild(place);
}
    </script>
    <title>Testing App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Am I At Risk?</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="userForm.php">Enter Details<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="governmentForm.php">Form for Government</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <br /><br /><br />
      <form>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label>Please enter the various places you visited in the past 14 days.</label>
          </div>
          <div id="p1">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 1</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place1" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date1"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am1" name="time1" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="am1">Morning</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm1" name="time1" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm1">Afternoon</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <div id="p2">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 2</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place2" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date2"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am2" name="time2" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="am2">Morning</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm2" name="time2" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm2">Afternoon</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <div id="p3">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 3</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place3" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date3"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am3" name="time3" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="am3">Morning</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm3" name="time3" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm3">Afternoon</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <div id="p4">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label"><b>Place 4</b></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="place4" placeholder="Enter Address of Place you Visited"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Enter the day you visited this place.</label>
                  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date4"></input>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="custom-control-label">Did you visit in the morning (A.M. times) or the afternoon (P.M. times)?</label>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="am4" name="time4" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="am4">Morning</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="pm4" name="time4" checked>
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="pm4">Afternoon</label>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <br />

          <div id="addedPlaces"></div>

          <button type="button" onclick="addPlace();">Add Place</button>


          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
    <!-- end of feature div  -->
   
  </body>
</html>
```